# Modifying iframe URL with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, flash, youtube

How can I modify the URL of an iframe, if it contains the `youtube.com` text?

I want to append:

`&amp;wmode=Opaque`

to it, but only if this argument doesn't already exist;

Tried:

```
$('iframe[src*=youtube.com]').attr('src',
   $(this).attr('src') + '&amp;wmode=Opaque');`
```

but I get an error:

> Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression:
>   [src*=youtube.com]

---

ok, I found out:

```
$('iframe[src*="youtube.com"]').each(function(){
  this.src += '&wmode=Opaque';
});
```

Comment: You get a syntax error because you need to quote the value: `src*='youtube.com'`.

Comment: With your last code you add '&wmode=Opaque' to the URL even if that param already exists.

Comment: you are right, do you know how can I check if it exists? is there some strpos function in javascript?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [jQuery API](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-contains-selector/) you want to do this:

```
$('iframe[src*=youtube.com]').attr('src',$(this).attr('src') + '&amp;wmode=Opaque');
$('iframe[src*="youtube.com"]').attr('src',$(this).attr('src') + '&amp;wmode=Opaque');
```

Note the double quotes around 'youtube.com'.

Answer (score 1):

I would do it in this way:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    function $_GET(key, src)
    {
        var re = new RegExp('[&|?]'+ key +'=([^&]*)','i');
        return (src = src.replace(/^\?/,'&').match(re)) ? src=src[1] : src='';
    }

    function appendToIframe(id, key, value)
    {
        var iframe = document.getElementById(id);
        var src = iframe.src;

        // Append desired key and value if key doesn't exist
        if (!$_GET(key, src))
        {
            var glue = (src.indexOf('?') == -1) ? '?' : '&';
            src += glue + key +'='+ value
        }

        iframe.src = src;           
    }


    </script>

<iframe src="your_url" id="iframeID"></iframe>

<a href="#" onclick="appendToIframe('iframeID', 'wmode', 'Opaque'); return false;">APPEND</a>
```

Just change `src` and `id` of the iframe tag as desired, and then use the function `appendToIframe` to **append a new couple of key and value to the iframe URL only if key is not already present**.

Please note that jQuery is not needed for that.